# How can I show a Bootstrap Modal while authentication time out in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have logged in and after 5 mins idle in need to show a bootstrap modal popup which is saying that session expired. Login again. I hava button in the modal which will redirect the application to login page. What is the best way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you're mixing terms, so let's be clear: sessions and authentication are two totally separate things. A client may have an active session, an active authentication or both, and the timeouts can be different for each.

Also, sessions and authentication employ different *types* of timeouts. Session timeouts are *sliding*, and are reset with each request. Authentication timeouts, however, are *absolute*, and expire at a defined time, whether or not the user is actively using the site.

If you're strictly talking about authentication, then probably the best way (or at least, most accurate way) is to long-poll an authenticated action via AJAX. For example:

```
[Authorize]
public void ActionResult CheckAuthentication()
{
}
```

There's no return here, because you don't need it. If the user's still authorized, you'll get a 200 status code. If not, you'll get a 401. If you get a 401, then you can pop your modal and prompt the user to login again.

Alternatively, you can simply keep a client-side timer. Since the authentication timeout is a fixed time from login, you just need to see how much time has passed from login to see if the authentication is still valid or not. To achieve this, you'll either need the timer stored in something like `localStorage` so it persists between requests, or you'll need to persist the login time in some way and calculate the time left from that.

The first approach is much easier, but will have the side effect of not allowing the session to expire. Each time you check the authentication status, you'll reset the session timeout. You could potentially avoid this problem, though, by simply indelibly tying the two together and destroying the session each login. Then, they'll both effectively "time out" at the same time.

The second approach won't effect the session timeout (since it doesn't involve repeated requests), but does require more work passing around a timer or login date value.